# finding a positive linear combination of a list of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I'm interested in finding linear combinations of rows of the following matrix such that every entry is either zero or positive. I'm not exactly sure what the best way to approach this problem is.

[   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  138 -102    0  122  244  -41    0    0   99 -205   41  122  -99    0 -244  183  -67    7]

[   0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  157 -116   -1  140  280  -47    0    0  113 -233   47  140 -113    0 -280  210  -76    8]

[   0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  176 -132    0  156  312  -52    0    0  126 -261   52  156 -126   -1 -312  236  -85    9]

[   0    0    0    1   -1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   51  -35    0   41   85  -12    1    1   34  -70   12   43  -34    0  -85   58  -18    2]

[   0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   88  -63    0   75  153  -24   -1    1   61 -126   24   76  -61    0 -153  110  -37    4]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  151 -114    0  137  270  -46    0    0  110 -228   46  135 -110    0 -270  206  -77    8]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  161 -119    0  142  285  -46    1    0  115 -238   46  143 -115    0 -285  211  -76    8]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  101  -73   -1   89  178  -30    0    0   72 -148   30   89  -72    0 -178  133  -47    5]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  164 -120    0  143  286  -46    0    0  116 -240   46  143 -116    0 -286  212  -76    8]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3   -2    0    2    5    0    1    0    2   -4    0    3   -2    0   -5    2    1    0]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  100  -74    0   88  176  -29    0    0   71 -147   29   88  -71   -1 -176  132  -47    5]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0  162 -119    0  142  284  -46    0    0  114 -238   46  142 -115    0 -284  211  -76    8]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0   78  -58    0   69  138  -23    0    0   56 -116   23   69  -56    0 -138  104  -38    4]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0  160 -118    0  141  282  -46    0    0  114 -236   46  141 -114    0 -282  210  -76    8]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0  142 -104    0  125  250  -41    0    0  101 -209   41  125 -101    0 -250  186  -67    7]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0  123  -90    0  107  216  -35    0    0   87 -180   35  108  -87    0 -216  160  -57    6]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   39  -29    0   35   70  -12    0    0   28  -58   12   35  -28    0  -70   53  -19    2]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1  101  -74    0   89  178  -29    0    0   72 -149   29   89  -72    0 -178  132  -48    5]

[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  201 -148    0  177  354  -58    0    0  143 -296   58  177 -143    0 -354  264  -95   10]

as an example, this vector of coefficients gives a solution, (i.e. the left matrix product is a vector with non-negative entries)

[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  2  0 -2]

any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set of $n$-component vectors $v_j$, $j=1\ldots,m$, the condition that the linear combination $\sum_j c_j v_j$ has all nonnegative entries is the set of linear inequalities $\sum_j c_j v_{jk} \ge 0$, $k = 1\ldots n$.  You can use linear programming methods to try to satisfy these inequalities.

Of course there is the trivial solution: all $c_j = 0$, but you probably don't want that.  You might add some constraint to avoid this solution (e.g. $\sum_j c_j \ge 1$).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Can you explain a little more what you mean by "you can use linear programming methods to try to satisfy these inequalities"? I have the matrices in Sage (a python based math software) but I'm not sure what tools I could use to solve these inequalities.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Sage, but it does have linear programming capabilities: see e.g. [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/SQ2014/thematic_tutorials/linear_programming.html#basic-linear-programs)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at that.